# Роутинг на Express + React

Tags: node.js, route, reactjs

Имеется реактовский роутер такого плана:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route name="main" path='/' component={App}/>
            <Route name="competitions" path='/competitions' component={Competitions}/>
            <Route name="contracts" path='/contracts' component={Contracts}/>
            <Route name="contract" path='/contract' component={Contract}/>
            <Route name="history" path='/history' component={PaymentHistory}/>
            <Route name="settings" path='/settings' component={Settings}/>
            <Route name="withdrawal" path='/withdrawal' component={Withdrawal}/>
            <Route name="confirm" path='/confirm' component={Confirm}/>
            <Route path='*' component={App} />
        </Router>
    ),
    document.getElementById("wrap")
);
```

на стороне сервера установлен обработчик к примеру:

```
app.use(function(request,response){
    console.log(1)
});
```

если отправлять вручную запрос на localhost:8080/ в консоль выводится 1, если же зайти с браузера по этому адресу то 0 эмоций. в чем проблема, подскажите ?

Comment: попробуйте что вроде такого: `app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 console.log(1);
});`

Comment: я тоже самое и делаю, по дефолту указан "/", так не работает все равно